MongoError when uploading excel on Laravel platform
I have been having this error on Laravel 11 when I try to upload an Excel document where my database is a MongoDB instance:

Transaction numbers are only allowed on a replica set member or mongos

Steps to reproduce

I installed Laravel 11

composer create-project laravel/laravel


I added Laravel Mongodb composer package

composer require mongodb/laravel-mongodb


I added the Laravel Excel composer package

composer require maatwebsite/excel:^3.1


Added some User Interface to facilitate the upload of the document. I am trying to upload assets into the web platform.

Created an AssetsImport document


php artisan make:import AssetsImport

The part that's producing the error is on this file,
class AssetsImport implements ToCollection 
{
  public function collection(Collection $collection) 
  {
     foreach ($collection as $key => $row) {
        $asset = Asset::where('asset_no', $row[2])->first();
        if($asset) {
            continue;
        }
        // add the upload code
        ....
     }
  }
}

The above script is meant to check if there's an existing Asset. If it's there, then don't add it (Continue with the foreach loop).
After checking this similar question, I still could not find a solution for this. Is this the correct way of implementing, and if so, how do I go about solving this error. I don't have control over the database (there's a Server Admin) so I cannot just add a replica set. Kindly assist.
This is the stacktrace of the error
{
  "message": "Transaction numbers are only allowed on a replica set member or mongos",
  "exception": "MongoDB\\Driver\\Exception\\BulkWriteException",
  "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Operation/InsertOne.php",
  "line": 126,
  "trace": [
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Operation/InsertOne.php",
      "line": 126,
      "function": "executeBulkWrite",
      "class": "MongoDB\\Driver\\Server",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Collection.php",
      "line": 878,
      "function": "execute",
      "class": "MongoDB\\Operation\\InsertOne",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/mongodb/laravel-mongodb/src/Collection.php",
      "line": 49,
      "function": "insertOne",
      "class": "MongoDB\\Collection",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/mongodb/laravel-mongodb/src/Query/Builder.php",
      "line": 678,
      "function": "__call",
      "class": "MongoDB\\Laravel\\Collection",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php",
      "line": 2026,
      "function": "insertGetId",
      "class": "MongoDB\\Laravel\\Query\\Builder",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/mongodb/laravel-mongodb/src/Eloquent/Builder.php",
      "line": 101,
      "function": "__call",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php",
      "line": 1338,
      "function": "insertGetId",
      "class": "MongoDB\\Laravel\\Eloquent\\Builder",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php",
      "line": 1303,
      "function": "insertAndSetId",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php",
      "line": 1142,
      "function": "performInsert",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/mongodb/laravel-mongodb/src/Eloquent/Model.php",
      "line": 749,
      "function": "save",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php",
      "line": 1069,
      "function": "save",
      "class": "MongoDB\\Laravel\\Eloquent\\Model",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php",
      "line": 359,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php",
      "line": 1068,
      "function": "tap"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/ForwardsCalls.php",
      "line": 23,
      "function": "create",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php",
      "line": 2340,
      "function": "forwardCallTo",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php",
      "line": 2352,
      "function": "__call",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/app/Imports/AssetsImport.php",
      "line": 55,
      "function": "__callStatic",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model",
      "type": "::"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/maatwebsite/excel/src/Sheet.php",
      "line": 268,
      "function": "collection",
      "class": "App\\Imports\\AssetsImport",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/maatwebsite/excel/src/Reader.php",
      "line": 116,
      "function": "import",
      "class": "Maatwebsite\\Excel\\Sheet",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/mongodb/laravel-mongodb/src/Concerns/ManagesTransactions.php",
      "line": 101,
      "function": "Maatwebsite\\Excel\\{closure}",
      "class": "Maatwebsite\\Excel\\Reader",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Operation/WithTransaction.php",
      "line": 63,
      "function": "MongoDB\\Laravel\\Concerns\\{closure}",
      "class": "MongoDB\\Laravel\\Connection",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/functions.php",
      "line": 537,
      "function": "execute",
      "class": "MongoDB\\Operation\\WithTransaction",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/mongodb/laravel-mongodb/src/Concerns/ManagesTransactions.php",
      "line": 107,
      "function": "MongoDB\\with_transaction"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/maatwebsite/excel/src/Transactions/DbTransactionHandler.php",
      "line": 30,
      "function": "transaction",
      "class": "MongoDB\\Laravel\\Connection",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/maatwebsite/excel/src/Reader.php",
      "line": 111,
      "function": "__invoke",
      "class": "Maatwebsite\\Excel\\Transactions\\DbTransactionHandler",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/maatwebsite/excel/src/Excel.php",
      "line": 154,
      "function": "read",
      "class": "Maatwebsite\\Excel\\Reader",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php",
      "line": 357,
      "function": "import",
      "class": "Maatwebsite\\Excel\\Excel",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/app/Http/Controllers/PagesController.php",
      "line": 53,
      "function": "__callStatic",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Facade",
      "type": "::"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php",
      "line": 54,
      "function": "handle_upload",
      "class": "App\\Http\\Controllers\\PagesController",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php",
      "line": 43,
      "function": "callAction",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php",
      "line": 260,
      "function": "dispatch",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php",
      "line": 206,
      "function": "runController",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Route",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
      "line": 806,
      "function": "run",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Route",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
      "line": 144,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php",
      "line": 50,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
      "line": 183,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authenticate.php",
      "line": 64,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
      "line": 183,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Auth\\Middleware\\Authenticate",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php",
      "line": 88,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
      "line": 183,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php",
      "line": 49,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
      "line": 183,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php",
      "line": 121,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php",
      "line": 64,
      "function": "handleStatefulRequest",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
      "line": 183,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php",
      "line": 37,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
      "line": 183,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php",
      "line": 75,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
      "line": 183,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
      "line": 119,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
      "line": 805,
      "function": "then",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
      "line": 784,
      "function": "runRouteWithinStack",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
      "line": 748,
      "function": "runRoute",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
      "line": 737,
      "function": "dispatchToRoute",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
      "line": 200,
      "function": "dispatch",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
      "line": 144,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php",
      "line": 21,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php",
      "line": 31,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
      "line": 183,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php",
      "line": 21,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TrimStrings.php",
      "line": 51,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
      "line": 183,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php",
      "line": 27,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
      "line": 183,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php",
      "line": 110,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
      "line": 183,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/HandleCors.php",
      "line": 49,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
      "line": 183,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\HandleCors",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.php",
      "line": 57,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
      "line": 183,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\TrustProxies",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
      "line": 119,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
      "line": 175,
      "function": "then",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
      "line": 144,
      "function": "sendRequestThroughRouter",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php",
      "line": 1168,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/public/index.php",
      "line": 17,
      "function": "handleRequest",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/anto/smartify/saptest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/resources/server.php",
      "line": 16,
      "function": "require_once"
    }
  ]
}


Is it relevant that you're uploading an Excel document? Please also extract a [mcve] and provide that along with the full output (i.e. backtrace) it produces.

Yes, I have tried both the .csv, .xls and .xlsx files
